# Database synonyms not working with ADF-Jdeveloper

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am working on a project that has synonyms exposed to us for development but when we use them in our EntityObjects/ViewObjects we are getting all the attributes(columns) from the database table as primary key. I tried checking the database tables in the Jdeveloper but its not showing the table constraints but the same is working in Toad.

I am using Jdeveloper - 12c version.

Comment: Did the EO wizard not show you the message that there is no primary key, do you want to set all the attributes as primary key? usually jdev does not recognize primary key form synonym

Comment: In the EO wizard all the attributes are shown as primary keys.. not sure why this is happening

Comment: Seems like somehow you are not seeing the message popup for specifying the primary keys for synonym based objects. You can also deselect the primary key attribute checkbox in the wizard for the attributes, which are not PK